# Putting a Linear regression solution together

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, pandas

https://gist.github.com/marcelcaraciolo/1321585

From this code, I am attempting to find the theta coefficients to a data set that I currently possess in a numpy array. I have saved the training array to a csv called 'foo.csv'.  I transformed my code from a different csv file through using the pandas library and currently my training set is 10886 rows by 12 columns. My first column is my Y or value I wish to predict, all other columns are variables what I hope to get theta values for.

This should mean I end up with a 12 by 1 matrix of theta values since there are 12 dependent variables.

Now I'm relatively new to Python. I am currently running iPython and want to feed in what my testing array is called, as I saved it as a csv file named 'foo.csv'. I am hoping to just be able to write [1] MVLR.calctheta(foo.csv) and have the output be a 12 by 1 matrix. But I am not getting that. I keep getting a:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calctheta'
```

But I have clearly saved calctheta as a function and am not understanding why I cannot call it. Have I declared this method incorrectly?
I'm assuming I can evaluate theta values, then run a for loop so that each test row is evaluated using these theta values and the dependant variables.

Where I'm running into an issue is this calctheta function that I've changed from the github above. I want it so I can just call calctheta with the csv file of

```
def calctheta(name):
    data = genfromtxt (name, delimiter=",")
    y = data[:,0]
    X = data[:,1:11]


    #number of training samples
    m = y.size

    y.shape = (m, 1)

    #Scale features and set them to zero mean
    x, mean_r, std_r = feature_normalize(X)

    #Add a column of ones to X (interception data)
    it = ones(shape=(m, 12))
    it[:, 1:12] = x

    #Some gradient descent settings
    iterations = 100
    alpha = 0.01

    #Init Theta and Run Gradient Descent
    theta = zeros(shape=(11, 1))

    theta, J_history = gradient_descent(it, y, theta, alpha, iterations)
    print theta
    plot(arange(iterations), J_history)
    xlabel('Iterations')
    ylabel('Cost Function')
    show()
```

On a side note, with this multi variable linear regression problem, there are numerous dependant variables. Some of my variables are determined on a ranked scale of 0 -- > how many options there are.

e.g. if 3 options for that column choice, there'd be distribution determined by training set but for other columns, it's the raw value so the mean is just that (e.g. of that is a temperature column)

My question is that when figuring out the theta values, the fact that variables are ranking options differently doesn't disqualify from using multi variable linear regression. I don't think it does if we assume that the end thing you're trying to measure is normally distributed relative to its inputs.

EDIT:

I added this to the top of my code and indented the remainder of my code with:

```
class MVLR:
```

I'm now getting

```
NameError: name 'calctheta' is not defined
```

EDIT 2:

My code

class MVLR:

```
from numpy import loadtxt, zeros, ones, array, genfromtxt, linspace, logspace, mean, std, arange
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import plot, show, xlabel, ylabel

#Evaluate the linear regression

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def feature_normalize(self.X):
    mean_r = []
    std_r = []
    X_norm = X
    n_c = X.shape[1]
    for i in range(n_c):
        m = mean(X[:, i])
        s = std(X[:, i])
        mean_r.append(m)
        std_r.append(s)
        X_norm[:, i] = (X_norm[:, i] - m) / s
    return X_norm, mean_r, std_r


def compute_cost(self, X, y, theta):
    '''
    Comput cost for linear regression
    '''
    #Number of training samples
    m = y.size

    predictions = X.dot(theta)

    sqErrors = (predictions - y)

    J = (1.0 / (2 * m)) * sqErrors.T.dot(sqErrors)

    return J


def gradient_descent(self, X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters):
    '''
    Performs gradient descent to learn theta
    by taking num_items gradient steps with learning
    rate alpha
    '''
    m = y.size
    J_history = zeros(shape=(num_iters, 1))

    for i in range(num_iters):

        predictions = X.dot(theta)

        theta_size = theta.size

        for it in range(theta_size):

            temp = X[:, it]
            temp.shape = (m, 1)

            errors_x1 = (predictions - y) * temp

            theta[it][0] = theta[it][0] - alpha * (1.0 / m) * errors_x1.sum()

        J_history[i, 0] = compute_cost(X, y, theta)

    return theta, J_history

#Load the dataset



#Plot the data
'''
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
n = 100
for c, m, zl, zh in [('r', 'o', -50, -25)]:
    xs = data[:, 0]
    ys = data[:, 1]
    zs = data[:, 2]
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=c, marker=m)
ax.set_xlabel('Size of the House')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Bedrooms')
ax.set_zlabel('Price of the House')
plt.show()
'''

def calctheta(self, name):
    data = genfromtxt (name, delimiter=",")
    y = data[:,0]
    X = data[:,1:11]


    #number of training samples
    m = y.size

    y.shape = (m, 1)

    #Scale features and set them to zero mean
    x, mean_r, std_r = feature_normalize(X)

    #Add a column of ones to X (interception data)
    it = ones(shape=(m, 12))
    it[:, 1:12] = x

    #Some gradient descent settings
    iterations = 100
    alpha = 0.01

    #Init Theta and Run Gradient Descent
    theta = zeros(shape=(11, 1))

    theta, J_history = gradient_descent(it, y, theta, alpha, iterations)
    print theta
    plot(arange(iterations), J_history)
    xlabel('Iterations')
    ylabel('Cost Function')
    show()
```

Comment: Can you post the whole file? In order to do something like 'MVLR.calctheta(foo.cv)' you actually need to have a class called MVLR which has the method calctheta. Sadly, just having the method in a file is not enough.

Comment: I added this to the top of my code and indented the remainder of my code with:

class MVLR:

I'm now getting

NameError: name 'calctheta' is not defined

Comment: What is the name of your source file? If it's `multlin.py` you should be able to type this into IPython: `import multlin; multlin.calctheta('foo.csv')`.

Comment: @yuzeh that is what i did and i'm still getting the same **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calctheta'**

Answer (score 0):

You should consider designing your code using Classes. You could make you file look something like this (partial code taken from your question):

```
from numpy import loadtxt, zeros, ones, array, genfromtxt, linspace, logspace, mean, std, arange
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import plot, show, xlabel, ylabel

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def calculate_theta(self, name):
       # code calculating theta here
       return theta

    def feature_normalize(self.X):
        mean_r = []
        std_r = []
        X_norm = X
        n_c = X.shape[1]
        for i in range(n_c):
           m = mean(X[:, i])
           s = std(X[:, i])
           mean_r.append(m)
           std_r.append(s)
           X_norm[:, i] = (X_norm[:, i] - m) / s
        return X_norm, mean_r, std_r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = MyClass(some_input_x)
    my_class.calculate_theta(some_input_y)
```

[Here](http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson08/) you can get a better example of how to create classes.

Comment: I added this to the top of my code and indented the remainder of my code with:

class MVLR:

I'm now getting

NameError: name 'calctheta' is not defined

Comment: Strange, I don't get this error. Is there to your code than you posted here? Maybe calctheta is being called somewhere else? (note: I've made some minor edits to my answer)

Comment: So in the terminal, I am now calling my function with 

    <CODE>Ninja = MVLR('foo.csv')</CODE>

It's giving me a 

    <CODE>TypeError: 'module' object is not callable</CODE>

Comment: Hey @user3042850, thanks for editing your question. I added some more code. I hope it's clear. You need to have the functions inside a Class so you can instantiate it and run its methods. You could, of course, just do MyClass.some_method(). Also check out the link I posted. I hope it helps! ;)

Comment: I don't have the **if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = MyClass(some_input_x)
    my_class.calculate_theta(some_input_y)**  but I am still getting an attribute error and i have no idea why - i have calctheta as a defined function and i am passing it, it's one parameter, the file i want to analyze

Comment: Yeah, you only need to add this part if you want to run your script from the command line.